# Images in Knowledge Rich text field not accessible in external pages

Tags: .net, rest, api, salesforce, rtf

Hello Stack community,

We are implementing Salesforce knowledge and obviously we do have multiple images in the Rich Text field (Description). We also have a parallel implementation to access this knowledge content from our website that runs on .NET through REST API.

In our website, we get all the content in this Rich Text Field but images come as broken, tried multiple ways but can't see images in the website. Our .NET dev says that he is getting html code for login page when accessing these images for which url is like "https://c.cs4.content.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=a1Vg0000000lTkK&feoid=00N20000003jcie&refid=0EMg00000009N4I"

Any suggestions on how to access inline images in Knowledge Rich Text Fields from external applications ?

Comment: I think this may help you get the type of responses from this community that you are after.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

That domain (c.cs4.content.force.com) is checking the session and hence the image is private.

Make the site public.

Also see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36503/how-to-set-public-inline-images-in-knowledge-base-article

Comment: Thanks Norman. But that link is when Sites is enabled in Salesforce. What is my instance does not have Sites enabled ?